# How to obtain percentiles containing decimal from an image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, reduceregion

I am trying to calculate the Fractional Vegetation Cover in Google earth engine, which requires the decimal percentile values of NDVI images within my study area, 99.5th percentile and 0.05th percentile for instance. However, the **ee.Reducer.percentile** function only provide integer percentiles. How should I code?

Here is an example script that demonstrates the issue:

```js
// Define a 1-band image.
var img = ee.Image("NASA/NASADEM_HGT/001").select('elevation');

var stats = img.reduceRegion({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.percentile([0.5, 1, 99, 99.5]),
  geometry:geometry,
  scale:30,
  maxPixels:1e13
});
print('stats', stats);
```

which triggers an error

```
Dictionary (Error)
Reducer.percentile: Duplicate output name 'p1'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-integer percentiles can be obtained by specifying the `outputNames` parameter of [ee.Reducer.percentile](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-reducer-percentile), as follows:

```js
// Copyright 2022 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

// Define a 1-band image.
var img = ee.Image("NASA/NASADEM_HGT/001").select('elevation')

var stats = img.reduceRegion({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.percentile({
    percentiles:[0.5, 1, 99, 99.5],
    outputNames: ['p00_5', 'p01_0', 'p99_0', 'p99_5']
  }),
  geometry:geometry,
  scale:30,
  maxPixels:1e13
});
print('stats', stats)
```

Script link:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/f2ac1802b8f633b4f0e7419848d69bbe